# Import Data to HIVE Table with a column value of more than one line

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a CSV File with a column containing data of more than one line. When I am trying to import data to HIVE Table, by default it takes one line and imports incorrect result.

Example File

1, "Line 1

Line 2", 12/23/2012

2, "Line 1 Line 2" 12/24/2012.

In this scenario, it treats first entry as two separate lines. What is the command to ease this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As if now Hive supports only the default Line Delimiter '\n'. So you will have to edit your file to import to Hive Table.

Answer (score 0):

Use following :

```
root@system>>cat file.txt
1,"Line 1
Line 2", 12/23/2012
2, "Line 1 Line 2" 12/24/2012.

root@system>> sed '{N;s/\n/ /g}' file.txt
```

Output is :

```
1,"Line 1 Line 2", 12/23/2012
2, "Line 1 Line 2" 12/24/2012.
```

[(N)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) add the next line to the work buffer.
Now you can parse further and store the data into Hive table.

Comment: Thank You for your answer. Sed is a Unix command, and I am working with Hadoop Command Line (HDP) on Windows Platform. Is there a command line option for Windows?

Comment: I got it to work on Windows, Data set I have is more complex were I have a column with 3 or more lines too. Using the above expression, I am not able to handle them as well as I noticed that the expression removes few rows from the dataset. Can you please help me address those issues.

Comment: Sure.Can you provide some rows from the dataset, so that I can help you?

Comment: I was able to copy only a row here. Message starting from "Bushwoods..." is a basically a 4 line message.

"2047618","2048986","2040910","","","","","false","false","14878921","User","Michael Hinckley","Bushwoods. Sounds good. 

Since there is no wifi. I can do a governance/user adoption/ case study best practice type of talk.

Or I can a SharePoint Online overview. 

Or a career in SP.",,"","","","2012-08-22T07:52:49.349-07:00",""